# Existence of complex branch for real exponents

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, winding-number

I've recently encountered a problem regarding complex branches that made me feel like there is something fundamental about branches I do not understand:

### The problem

Let $G$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and $z_1,z_2,...z_m \in \mathbb C \setminus G$ be distinct points such that there are real numbers $a_1,a_2,...a_m$ satisfying:
$$\sum_{j=1}^ma_jInd_\gamma(z_j)=0$$
for every closed path $\gamma \subset G$.

Show that there is a holomorphic branch of $(z-z_1)^{a_1}(z-z_2)^{a_2}...(z-z_m)^{a_m}$ in $G$.

### My confusion

The basic idea behind the statement of the problem seems intuitively obvious to me, but I've had great difficulty expressing a solution rigurously, which makes me believe there's something fundamental I'm missing here.

My approach was to try and utilize a theorem that states $logf$ has a holomorphic branch in $G$ if and only if $$\int_\gamma \frac{f'}{f}dz=0$$
for every closed path $\gamma \subset G$.

However, the only sensible way I can think of to define $f$ is by $f=\exp[\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_jlog(z-z_j)]$

Obviously if the exponent is holomorphic, so is $f$, but how can it be shown that it is indeed holomorphic? Induction does not work because the separate $log(z-z_j)$ may not exist on their own, even though their weighted sum does.

It is also quite simple to show that $f$ as defined in the problem satisfies the conditions of the theorem, and hence the sum of logarithms in the above exponent is indeed holomorphic.. but that presumes that $f$ exists (and is holomorphic) in the first place.

Can $f$ be defined in some other way that makes this all fall into place?

Comment: The winding number of the path $\gamma$ about the point $z_j$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be possible to prove an even stronger statement than the one stated in the question. Suppose that, instead of assuming that $\sum_j a_j {\rm \ Ind}_{\gamma} (z_j) = 0$ for all closed loops $\gamma \subset G$, we merely assume that 
$$ \sum_j a_j {\rm \ Ind}_{\gamma} (z_j) \in \mathbb Z$$

for all closed loops $\gamma \subset G$. With this weaker assumption, I think it should still be possible to prove that $ \prod_{j = 1}^m (z - z_j)^{a_j}$ has a holomorphic branch in $G$.

---

Before we start addressing this question, we shall prove some useful lemmas.

**Lemma 1:** Suppose $f$ is a holomorphic function on an open set $U$ such that $\oint_\gamma f(z')dz' = 0$ for all closed contours $\gamma \subset U$. Then the function
$$F(z) = \int_{\gamma_{c \to z}} f(z') dz'$$

is well-defined and holomorphic in $U$, with derivative $F'(z) = f(z)$. (Here, $c$ is an arbitrary fixed point in $U$, and for every $z\in U$, $\gamma_{c \to z }$ denotes any path from $c$ to $z$ in $U$; the "well-defined" part of the statement is that the value of the integral in this definition does not depend on the choice of path $\gamma_{c \to z}$, as long as this path is contained within $U$.)

**Proof:** The well-definedness follows immediately from the fact that the difference between two paths $c \to z$ is a closed contour, on which the integral wanishes.
For holomorphicity, pick any $w \in U$, and pick any open ball $U_w \subset U$ of $w$. On this open ball, we can write
$$ F(z) = \int_{[w \to z]} f(z') dz' + F(w)$$
where $[w \to z]$ denotes the straight line segment from $w$ to $z$. Hence, for any $z \in U_w \setminus \{ w \}$,
$$  \frac{F(z) - F(w)}{z - w} - f(w) = \frac{1}{z - w} \int_{[w \to z]} \left( f(z') - f(w) \right) dz' $$
which tends to zero as $z$ tends to $w$, by the continuity of $f(z')$ at $w$.

**Lemma 1a:** Suppose $f$ is a holomorphic function on an open set $U$, such that $\oint_\gamma f(z') dz' \in 2\pi i \mathbb Z$ for all closed contours $\gamma \subset U$. Then the function
$$ g(z) = \exp\left( \int_{\gamma_{c \to z} }f(z') dz' \right)$$
is well-defined and holomorphic in $U$. (Again, for every $z \in U$, $\gamma_{c \to z}$ denotes any path from $c$ to $z$ that is contained within $U$.)

**Proof:** The well-definedness follows from the fact that if $\gamma_{c \to z}$ and $\gamma'_{c \to z}$ are two paths from $c$ to $z$, contained within $U$, then
$$ \exp \left( \oint_{\gamma'_{c \to z}} f(z') dz' \right) = \exp \left( \oint_{\gamma_{c \to z}} f(z') dz' + 2\pi i n\right) = \exp \left( \oint_{\gamma_{c \to z}} f(z') dz' \right). $$
To prove holomorphicity, pick any $w \in U$, and pick an open ball $U_w \subset U$ of $w$. Fix any path $\gamma_{c \to w}$, and consider the function $F : U_w \to \mathbb C$ defined by
$$ F(z) = \int_{\gamma_{w \to z}} f(z') dz' + k_c,$$
where $k_c = \int_{\gamma_{c \to w}} f(z') dz'$ with $\gamma_{c \to w}$ being our chosen fixed path, and where $\gamma_{w \to z}$ denotes any path from $w$ to $z$ within $U_w$. $F(z)$ is well-defined and holomorphic on the open ball $U_w$ by virtue of Lemma 1, since for any closed loop $\gamma \subset U_w$, we have $\oint_\gamma f(z') dz' = 0$ because the open ball $U_w$ is simply-connected.
Since $g(z) = \exp(F(z))$ on $U_w$, it follows that $g(z)$ is also holomorphic on $U_w$. As our choice of $w$ was arbitrary, this proves that $g(z)$ is holomorphic everywhere in $U$.

**Lemma 2**: For any $z_0 \in \mathbb C$, and for any path $\gamma_{a \to b} \subset \mathbb C \setminus \{ z_0 \}$ from $a$ to $b$, we have
$$ \exp\left(\int _{\gamma_{a \to b}} \frac{1}{z' - z_0} dz'\right) = \frac{b - z_0}{a - z_0}.$$

[Really, this lemma is saying that $\int _{\gamma_{a \to b}} \frac{1}{z' - z_0} dz' = \log(b - z_0) - \log(a - z_0)$.  But I have deliberately avoided writing it this way so that we don't have to worry about ambiguities in defining logarithms.]

**Proof:**
We first prove this statement for the special case where $\gamma_{a \to b}$ is contained inside some simply-connected subset $U$ of $\mathbb C \setminus \{ z_0 \}$. In this special case, Lemma 1 tells us that the function
$$ F(z) = \int_{\gamma_{a \to z}} \frac{1}{z' - z_0} dz'$$
is well-defined on $U$ (i.e. the integral in this definition does not depend on the choice of the path $\gamma_{a \to z}$ from $a$ to $z$, as long as this path $\gamma_{a \to z}$ is contained within our simply-connected open neighbourhood $U$). Lemma 1 also tells us that $$F'(z) = \frac{1}{z - z_0}.$$ By the product rule for differentiation, we have
$$ \frac{d}{dz} \left( \frac{\exp(F(z))}{z - z_0}\right) = 0$$
on $U$. Therefore, $ \exp(F(z))$ is a constant multiple of $z - z_0$. We can identify the value of the constant as $1/(a - z_0)$ from the fact that $\exp(F(a)) = 1$. Thus
$$ \exp(F(z)) = \frac{z - z_0}{a - z_0}$$
for all $z \in U$, and the result follows by taking $z = b$.

For the general case, we cover $\mathbb C \setminus \{ z_0 \}$ with the two simply-connected open sets $$U = \mathbb C \setminus [z_0 -\infty, z_0], \ \  \ \ \ V = \mathbb C \setminus [z_0, z_0 + \infty],$$ where $[z_0 - \infty, z_0]$ (resp. $[z_0, z_0 + \infty]$) denote the left-pointing (resp. right-pointing) straight horizontal half-lines originating at $z_0$.
Any path $\gamma_{a \to b} \subset \mathbb C \setminus \{ z_0 \} $, can be broken down into finitely many segments,
$$ \gamma_{a \to c_1}, \ \gamma_{c_1 \to c_2}, \ \dots, \ \gamma_{c_{n-1} \to b},$$
where each segment $\gamma_{c_{i} \to c_{i+1}}$ is either wholly contained in $U$ or is wholly contained in $V$. (The fact that we can find finitely many such segments is a consequence of  $\gamma_{a \to b}$ being compact.)
By the special case, we have
$$ \exp \left( \int_{\gamma_{c_i \to c_{i+1}}} \frac{1}{z' - z_0}dz'\right) = \frac{c_{i+1} - z_0}{c_i - z_0},$$
for each segment $\gamma_{c_i \to c_{i+1}}$, and hence
$$  \exp \left( \int_{\gamma_{a, b}} \frac{1}{z' - z_0}dz'\right) = \frac{c_1 - z_0}{a - z_0}. \frac{c_2 - z_0}{c_1 - z_0}. \dots .\frac{b - z_0}{c_{n-1} - z_0} = \frac{b - z_0}{a - z_0} $$

---

**Proof of main result:** By definition,
$$ \prod_{j=1}^m (z - z_j)^{a_j} = \exp \left( \sum_{j=1}^m a_j \log (z - z_j)  \right). $$
So to prove that $\prod_{j=1}^m (z - z_j)^{a_j}$ has a holomorphic branch on our open set $G \subset \mathbb C \setminus \{ z_1, \dots, z_n \}$, we must prove that there exists a 
holomorphic function $g(z)$, defined on the whole of $G$, such that for any $w \in G$, there exists an open neighbourhood $U_w \subset  G$ and holomorphic functions $u_{w, j}(z)$ defined on $U_w$ (for $j \in \{ 1, \dots m \}$) such that 
$$ g(z) = \exp \left( \sum_{j=1}^m a_j u_{w, j}(z) \right) $$
for all $z \in U_w$, and such that
$$ \exp(u_{w,j}(z)) = z - z_j$$
for all $z \in U_w$ and for all $j \in \{1, \dots m \}$.

[Effectively, the function $u_{w,j}(z)$ is a local representative of $\log(z - z_j)$ in the neighbourhood $U_w$ of $w$.]

To construct such a $g(z)$, we observe that for any closed contour $\gamma \subset G$, we have
$$ \oint_\gamma  \sum_{j=1}^m \frac{a_j}{z' - z_j} dz' = 2\pi i\sum_{j=1}^m a_j {\rm \ Ind}_{\gamma}(z_j) \in 2\pi i \mathbb N.$$
This observation enables us to define the function $g : G \to \mathbb C$ using the expression,
$$ g(z) = \exp \left( \int_{\gamma_{c \to z}} \sum_{j=1}^m \frac{a_j}{z' - z_j} dz' + \sum_{j = 1}^m a_j  k_{c,j} \right).$$

Here, $c$ is some arbitrary fixed point in $G$, and for each $j$, $k_{c,j}$ is a constant such that $$\exp(k_{c, j}) = c - z_j.$$ Meanwhile, $\gamma_{c \to z}$ denotes any path in $G$ from $c $ to $z$. By Lemma 1a, the integral in this definition only depends on the choice of $\gamma_{c \to z}$ up to additive shifts of $2\pi i$, ensuring that $g(z)$ is well-defined in $G$. Lemma 1a also tells us that the function $g(z)$ defined in this way is holomorphic in $G$.

Now pick any $w \in G$, and pick a path $\gamma_{c\to w} \subset G$ from $c$ to $w$. Let $U_w$ be an open ball around $w$. Because $U_w$ is simply-connected, we have $$\oint_\gamma \frac{1}{z' - z_j} dz'= 0$$ for all $j$ and for all closed contours $\gamma \in U_w$. So it makes sense to define functions $u_{w, j} : U_w \to \mathbb C$ using the expression,
$$ u_{w, j} (z) = \int_{\gamma_{w \to z}} \frac{1}{z' - z_j} dz' + k_{w, j}.$$ 
Here, the constants $k_{w, j}$ are defined by the formula
$$ k_{w, j} = k_{c, j} + \int_{\gamma_{c \to w}} \frac{1}{z' - z_j} dz', $$
where $\gamma_{c \to w}$ is the path in $G$ from $c$ to $w$ that we have fixed.  Meanwhile, in the definition of $u_{w,j}(z)$,  $\gamma_{w \to z}$ denotes any path in $U_w$ from $w$ to $z$; Lemma 1 ensures that the integral in the definition does not depend on the precise choice of path, and that the function $u_{w, j}(z)$ defined in this way is holomorphic in $U_w$.

It is clear from the definitions that

$$ g(z) = \exp \left( \sum_{j = 1}^m a_j u_{w, j}(z) \right)$$

for all $z \in U_w$. Applying  Lemma 2 to the definition of $k_{w, j}$ gives $$\exp(k_{w, j}) = w - z_j$$ for each $j$, and by applying Lemma 2 once more, this time to the definition of $u_{w,j}(z)$, we learn that

$$ \exp(u_{w, j}(z)) = z - z_j$$
for all $z \in U_w$ and for all $j$. So $g(z)$ and the $u_{w, j}(z)$'s obey all the desired properties on $U_w$. Since the choice of $w$ was arbitrary, the proof is complete.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why it suffices that $g$ agree with a particular $g_U$ and we do not require that it agrees with a representative in any simply connected $U$?

Comment: @BarAlon I have rewritten this answer using a more explicit argument. I hope this one is clearer. (If you ever wish to revisit the old argument, then click on the "edited" hyperlink at the bottom of the answer.) Sorry about the confusion!

Comment: I think the key concept I was missing is that while the individual logs aren't defined globally they are defined locally. So what we really mean by a branch is a global function that agrees , in a neighborhood of each point, with a local function defined standardly

Comment: @BarAlon Yes. It took me a while to realise that this is a good way to interpret the statement. But this is great. I learn a lot by thinking about problems on this site.